# Insert data to database with FK relation

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, code-first, sql-server-2016-express

I use code-first to generate the database and data at runtime.

My two classes/models have one-to-many relationship. As a FK cannot be null I first insert a **Standard** before inserting a **Student**, and I also manually type in the FK ID as well. Yet I still get `System.NullReferenceException` and I just cannot understand why?

I tried googling but I cannot find related article on inserting data with foreign relation from scratch in code-first.

**My Entity Class/Model**

```
public class Student {
    public Student() { }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public int StandardId { get; set; } // FK StandardId
    public Standard Standard { get; set; } }

public class Standard {
    public Standard() { }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; } 

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } }
```

**My Main**

```
using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    Standard std = new Standard();
    ctx.Standards.Add(std);
    ctx.SaveChanges(); // Database already has a StandardID = 1

    Student stud = new Student()
    {
        StudentName = "John",
        StandardId = 1  // I even manually type in the FK
    };

    ctx.Student.Add(stud); // I still get 'System.NullReferenceException'
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manually add your `StandardId`, do this:

```
using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    Standard std = new Standard();

    Student stud = new Student()
    {
        StudentName = "John",
    };

    stud.Standard = std;

    ctx.Student.Add(stud);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

EF will take care of the relation.

Comment: I agree, do not add the entities separately, but be careful when you try to update the related tables under your root entity. It's different then `Add` operation. For update you have to iterate over your whole tree and set them modified or `Attach` them.

Comment: Do you mean even with EF I still have to loop through each entry and compare its original state and set them modified manually?

Comment: For scalar types no need to worry about them. Have a look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Types-of-Entities.aspx for entity types. However, for navigation properties, yes you have to take care of them separately if you are working with detached objects (as far as I know, updates are welcome).